# Apply min to every element in array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function:

```
def cdf_inv(cdf, l):
    s = np.arange(0,255)
    return np.min(s[cdf[s] >= l])
```

where the expected input `cdf` is an array with 255 elements and `l` is a *single* value. I wish to extend this function so that instead of taking a single value, it takes an array of values and apply the same semantics on each element. Specifically, I want to replace `l` with an array(potentially multidimensional) where each element corresponds to a different `l`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: How does the index of `l` map to `cdf`?

Comment: Could you show sample input and output (use arrays much smaller than 255 for the example)?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I updated the OP to make it simpler :)

Comment: No, you did not make it clearer.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm okay. Edit reverted then. `cdf` is a normalized histogram with 255 elements

Comment: Why don't you just show sample data and results?

Comment: What you have there returns the index of the first element of `cdf` that is >= `l`.  So, are you looking to return an array `x[i]` where `x[i]` is the index in `cdf` of the first element that is >= `l[i]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes sir!

Comment: Just to double-check, you want the FIRST element, and not the CLOSEST element?  So, if cdf is [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] and `l` is 4, you want 0, and not 5?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to do this without a loop.  This seems to do what you ask.  It returns the first element in `cdf` greater than or equal to each element of `l` in turn.

```
def cdf_inv(cdf, l):
    return [np.argwhere(cdf > ll)[0][0] for ll in l]
```